# How to force subclass to implement setter (and getter) for an abstract property (in Pycharm)?

Tags: python-3.x, subclass, abstract, getter, setter

According to documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), abstract setter (and getter) should be defined as:

```
class C(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_property(self):
        ...
    @my_abstract_property.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_property(self, val):
        ...
```

I have created an example:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class C(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_property(self):
        pass

    @my_abstract_property.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_property(self, val):
        pass

class D(C):
    my_abstract_property = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = C()
```

If I run it, I get an error: "`TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class C with abstract methods my_abstract_property`" which is OK.

if I change `if __name__ == "__main__"` part of code to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = D()
    print(x.my_abstract_property)
    x.my_abstract_property = 5
    print(x.my_abstract_property)
```

Output is:

```
1
5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see in class D() I am not forced to implement setter at all.
Furthermore, while using Pycharm for impolementation of class D(), if I press alt+enter, implement abstract methods, I get only one option: `my_abstract_property(self: C)`. After choosing this single option, only getter is generated by Pycharm:

```
@property
def my_abstract_property(self):
    pass
```

So, my question is how to force subclass to implement setter (and getter) for an abstract property (in Pycharm)?